# Is there any check to keep moderators and users >2,000 reputation from editing questions?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Just see what a moderator is doing on Stack Overflow:

[image]

I am new to Stack Overflow. After viewing some edited questions, I noticed that some users with 100k, 59k, 39k, 11k, ... reputation just edit without answering questions. Around 350 suggested edits need to be approved. But they are just editing questions - like capitalising 'Chrome', 'Firefox', added only a snippet that isn't really needed, removing a tag. And then closing these questions. What is the point of these edits I don't know! I don't see these users approving others' suggested edits.

Even some of them downvoted me for answering a question. In HTML one can hide something just using "hidden" attribute, but I did it using CSS.

Is there any system that they get suspended from editing for 1/3/7 day(s)? Or users with more than 2k rep don't get +2 rep from editing?

Comment: Users with more than 2k rep don't get any reputation from editing.

Comment: Your complaint is that unpaid volunteers need to do *more* free work but you should direct what it is?

Comment: Highly relevant if you haven't seen it yet: https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: @Gourav editing and voting is orthogonal to answering.

Comment: "downvote" != "I know the answer", the explanation for the downvote is present in the tooltip and it says "_This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful_"

Comment: 3 users thought that the answer did not show any research effort; was unclear or not useful.

Comment: @Gourav no I have not read that question / answer and my previous comment was not related to that. I was replying to your comment which mentioned "_They must know the answer that's why the downvoted._"

Comment: @Gourav What does getting 3 downvotes on an answer have to do with edits on a question? *Even if* the one doing the edit *separately* downvoted your answer (that's a big if - you really have no way of knowing) then *two other people* also found the answer worthy of a downvote.

Comment: Maybe I missed it in your post, but why are users with > 2k who edit questions a problem? They don't get reputation from that, they don't need to be reviewed so they don't clog the review queue.

Comment: "they are just editing questions - like capitalising 'Chrome', 'Firefox'" -- oh my, that's terrible. Fortunately there's an easy way to avoid it -- just spell things correctly in the first place.

Comment: @Gourav - Editing contributions are encouraged. Your complaints are unwarranted. Your contributions don’t belong to you they belong to the community

Comment: @Gourav: you do realise that your question can be downvoted by somebody who does not follow the mentioned tag? :-)

Answer (score 21):

> Just see what a moderator is doing on Stack Overflow:

There is more than enough "unblurred" information in the screenshot to see who you're talking about, not that it really matters. These edit summaries also don't help make your point; you could have just straight out said what you find objectionable.

> After viewing some edited questions, I noticed that some users with 100k, 59k, 39k, 11k, ... reputation just edit without answering questions.

Yes. This is a [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) that is extended to them on the basis of reputation. In particular, their edits do not require approval from the site - so they don't clog the edit-review system.

> But they are just editing questions - like capitalising 'Chrome', 'Firefox', added only a snippet that isn't really needed, removing a tag.

It improves the post, and it's volunteer work. What is there to complain about?

> And then closing these questions.

*When* this happens, it has **nothing to do with** the edit.

Questions that should be closed, should be closed. In no case does third-party (i.e., not by the OP) editing change that - because if the problems with the question can be fixed straightforwardly, we do that *instead of* voting to close.

Question closure is for problems with the question that either fundamentally cannot be solved, or which can only be solved by OP's input. It absolutely can happen that there is such a problem, and *also* something minor that a trusted user can fix.

> What is the point of these edits I don't know!

The point of capitalizing words that should be capitalized, is to ensure that words that should be capitalized, are capitalized, Similarly for the other edits. I don't understand how there can be any confusion about this.

> I don't see these users approving others' suggested edits.

Well, yes, of course you don't **see** it. Why would you see it? First off, there are many people qualified to approve edits (all the same people that you're complaining about), who are on the site at varying hours around the clock and across the week. Any one of them might see, or not see, any proposed edit. Second, the proposed edits are being made by many other users. The system is not going to notify you about those edits being approved, because they aren't *your* proposal.

So why would you see anything?

But yes, edits do get approved all the time. The queue is full in part because it takes a best two-out-of-three decision from these same people who are allowed to just make the edit themselves, and because finding edits to approve requires going out of one's way to look at the queue. (By the way, they get zero reputation for either making these approval decisions, nor for editing directly.)

> Even some of them downvoted me for answering a question.

Please do not attempt to answer questions that clearly should be closed. That makes it harder to keep the site clean. The reason we close questions is **exactly to prevent you** from trying to answer them, until (assuming it's feasible) the question is fixed up to standards.

But no, **you** do not get downvoted - your answer does. Because an answer on a question that should be closed, is not useful.

> In HTML one can hide something just using "hidden" attribute, but I did it using CSS.

I assume you're talking about some particular answer here that got downvoted. This is not relevant here.

> Is there any system that they get suspended from editing for 1/3/7 day(s)?

Users can be suspended from the site *generally* for abusive behaviour. However, **you have shown no reason why** anyone in particular should be prevented from making edits. There is nothing wrong with the sort of editing that you show. There are plenty of good, useful edits that can be made with only minor changes.

Personally, I think it is normally not worth the effort, for something that needs to be closed anyway - since, if the OP does provide more information (or focus the question on a specific problem, or whatever else needed to be fixed), it will probably need to be edited again for grammar etc. anyway.

Sometimes I will do this sort of thing for a *duplicate*, because I expect that it's likely to hang around - not deleted, and not reopened.

> Or users with more than 2k rep don't get +2 rep from editing?

Yes, that's how it works. The [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) is very clear that you get +2 rep for **having a suggested edit approved** - not for editing.

People who make edits like this are very definitely not motivated by reputation. Even if they could get +2 for making an edit, and also didn't care about the site's quality - a lot of the time they could get +25 for answering a question that should not be answered.